Design mapping many to many in ASP .NET MVC
I'm new to auto mapper in asp .net mvc, I have a small problem and need your help. The image below is my database with 3 tables in which trainer vs course is many to many (1 trainer can join many courses and vice versa, 1 course can have many trainers), creating an intermediate table to make feedback statistics for the course and that trainer. I want to ask about how to design ViewModels to most conveniently query the feedback statistics screen including Trainer name, course information, feedback information, in addition there are 2 additional fields that are not in the database: numberOfFeedback and AverageFbScore. My idea is to just create a view model named ResponseVM that defines all fields including 2 fields not in the db however it is really complicated to work with mapper. I also tried to solve it the traditional way by querying linq as usual and then creating a new ViewModel object equal to the data fields in the database. However, the project's requirement is to use AutoMapper, please help me.
Here's my traditional way of doing it without using a map:
public IActionResult ViewTrainerFeedbackedList()
{
    var trainerFeedbacks = (from trainer in _context.Trainers
                            join feedback in _context.Feedbacks on trainer.Id equals feedback.TrainerId
                            join course in _context.Courses on feedback.CourseId equals course.Id
                            group feedback by new
                            {
                                TrainerName = trainer.Name,
                                CourseName = course.Name,
                                CourseStartDate = course.StartDate,
                                CourseEndDate = course.EndDate,
                                CourseNumberOfTrainee = course.NumberOfTrainee
                            } into feedbackGroup
                            select new FeedbackVM
                            {
                                TrainerName = feedbackGroup.Key.TrainerName,
                                CourseName = feedbackGroup.Key.CourseName,
                                CourseStart = feedbackGroup.Key.CourseStartDate,
                                CourseEnd = feedbackGroup.Key.CourseEndDate,
                                NumberOfTrainee = feedbackGroup.Key.CourseNumberOfTrainee,
                                NumberOfFeedback = feedbackGroup.Count(),
                                FeedbackScore = feedbackGroup.Average(f => f.Score)
                            }).ToList();

    return View(trainerFeedbacks);

}

my database
The answer must be clear with me
